# Cordova: use window.open in child browser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, window.open, childbrowser

I have a requirement of showing pdf on click of a link in child browser, how can I achieve it? I'm using iOS and Android apps created using cordova

Answer (score 0):

Add [`cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) Plugin

```
var wsUrl = "your PDF URL";
window.open(wsUrl, '_blank');
```

Comment: @Ramprasnth: I want to open pdf on clicking a link inside child browser page. The answer doesnot agree with the question asked